# How to add additional files to adobe air installer?

Tags: apache-flex, installation, air, flexbuilder

I've created an AIR application, but it uses an external SWF for extra functionality. I want that SWF to be included in the install, but currently it's not. Is there anyway I can get FlexBuilder or any other tool to include this extra file in the installer? I've tried manually adding the file (as a .air file is just a zip file in disguise), but there must be hash checks inside the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place the SWF file in your application's **src** directory it will give you the option to include in the installer (previously I tried putting it in the application's root folder).

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in Flash, go to File>Adobe AIR 2.0 Settings. At the bottom of the dialgoue box is a list of included files. Add your SWF to that list.

Answer (score 1):

What if you wanted to add a text file instead to the installer using Flex Builder? I tried to add it using the export release build wizard, but I don't see the text file generated in the application directory...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a custom builder, under project -> properties -> builders

I use something like the following for one of my projects that I want to package some mxml and as files with so that the compiler doesn't try to compile them on export. Save the xml below as something like copy_files.xml and add a new Ant Builder to your project. Under the targets tab of the builder I have mine set to run the copy-files target on every clean.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="SampleProject">
    <target name="copy-files" description="Copy Source Files">
            <copy todir="bin-debug/sources">
                <fileset dir="sources" >
                    <include name="**/*.*" />
                </fileset>
            </copy>
            <copy todir="bin-release/sources">
                <fileset dir="sources" >
                    <include name="**/*.*" />
                </fileset>
            </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```